# Jumpy touchpad drivers on Dell Inspiron and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, touchpad, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron has a jumpy touchpad issue. Most websites and support forums say that one thing I should do is to update drivers. **Alas**, Dell does not produce Windows 10 drivers for Dell-Inspiron laptops. What can be done? Should I install new Windows-8 drivers and hope for the best?

Answer (score 1):

I also upgraded my inspiron and ran into issues not only with touch pad only. I tried a couples of things downloaded the new windows drivers but they worked for a couple of days but with issues.

What ended up working for me was using the drivers which came with the laptop on the new operating system. i had them backed up so am not sure if you did with yours. another thing to note is that with [dell drivers you need to install them in a certain order](http://accatech.com/install-dell-drivers-proper-order/)

If using the latest make the operating system is also updated and it contains fixes